# How to filter values in ng-repeat by partial string property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller with products and filterStr variables:

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.products = [
       { id: 1, name: 'Michael', data: 'Berlin' },
       { id: 2, name: 'Maria', data: 'Moscow'}
       { id: 3, name: 'Alex', data: 'Aragon'},
       { id: 4, name: 'Mara', data:'Paris' }
       /*... etc... */
   ];

 $scope.filterStr = 'ar';
});
```

Here ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { name: filterStr }">
```

In ng-repeat above I want to display objects only that has inside name property this combination of letters `ar`:

```
id: 2, name: 'Maria', data: 'Berlin'  
id: 4, name: 'Mara', data:'Paris'
```

What is the best way to implement the desired filter in angularjs?

Comment: [Works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeIwa3Hs16EPvXcMd3sI). Not sure what problem is

Answer (score 2):

You can try custom filter

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | search:'name':'ar' "> 
  {{product.name}}
</div>   

 app.filter('search', function() {

      return function(input,key,searchText) {

        var out = [];    
        angular.forEach(input, function(obj) {

            if(obj[key]){
              var text = obj[key].search(searchText) 
              if(text > 0) {
                out.push(obj);
              }            
            } 

        });
        return out;
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Many thanks to @vignesh for a great answer! The code @vignesh provided encourage me to make such an implementation in my own project!

**Second:** While trying to implement this filter myself, I've noticed that this solution can be improved a little bit more...

```
app.filter('search', function() 
{
    return function(list, field, partialString) 
    {
        // if the search string is invalid or empty - return the entire list
        if (!angular.isString(partialString) || partialString.length == 0) return list;

        var results = [];

        angular.forEach(list, function(item) 
        {
            if (angular.isString(item[field]))
            {
                if (item[field].search(new RegExp(partialString, "i")) > -1)
                {
                     results.push(item);    
                }
            }
        });

        return results;
    }

});
```

I then used it with a search input and a repeater

```
<input ng-model="myPartialSearchString" />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | search:'name':myPartialSearchString "> 
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the filter function from angular:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.$">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"> Exact match only
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: filter:search:strict">
```